# Using setNdefPushMessage in loop in Android

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

Can I send multiple NDEF messages using `setNdefPushMessageCallback` or `setNdefPushMessage` like in a loop from one activity in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use those methods wherever and as often as you want within your activity's code. However, only the last message set before any peer-to-peer (Beam) communication will be transfered by Android. Messages that you previously set will simply be dropped.

So you can only send *one* NDEF message over a peer-to-peer connection.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Roland. Also can u pls tell me if I can send NDEF message to another reader without using Android Beam service on my Android Device?

Comment: @Sathiya If you want to send data using peer-to-peer mode, your only option is to use Android Beam. For other scenarios see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24096356/2425802) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25157878/2425802).